# Uncrustify edit file instead of piping in Windows

Tags: batch-file, code-formatting, uncrustify

How would one directly change the file being formatted by Uncrustify in Windows? All the docs suggest is to pipe the standard output to another file. Is there a clean batch script or a way in Uncrustify to just change the file directly?

I tried doing a script like the following:

```
for /R %%f in (..\..\..\src\Funs\*.c) do (
..\..\Uncrustify\uncrustify -c ..\..\Uncrustify\g.cfg -f %%f > %%f
)
```

The problem is that the file ends up empty, which makes sense. I just don't know a workaround

Comment: When the command interpreter recognises an output redirection `>`, it opens (creates) the related file for being written with the file pointer (re-)set to zero, so it becomes an empty file; I don't see a good work-around for this...

Answer (score 0):

--replace is your friend (without -f):

```
for /R %%f in (..\..\..\src\Funs\*.c) do (
..\..\Uncrustify\uncrustify -c ..\..\Uncrustify\g.cfg --replace %%f
)
```